# How to use same function for different IDs in Javascript using If statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have to open different Modals based on the onClick event on IDs using same Function. I'm using If condition to check, but it is always taking the first condition to be true. Please help.

```
//html
<div id="Remote-Parking" class="element parking" onclick="modalFunction()">Remote-Parking</div>
<div id="Emergency-Braking" class="element collision-detection" onclick="modalFunction()">Emergency-Braking</div>


//javascript
function modalFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById('Emergency-Braking').onclick) {
        document.getElementById('Popup-Emergency-Braking').style.display="block";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('Remote-Parking').onclick) {
        document.getElementById('Popup-Remote-Parking').style.display="block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the way you have asked the questioned, my answer is following. Hope it will help you

```html
<div id="Remote-Parking" class="element parking" onclick="modalFunction( this.id )">Remote-Parking</div>
<div id="Emergency-Braking" class="element collision-detection" onclick="modalFunction( this.id )">Emergency-Braking</div>

<script>
function modalFunction( id ) {
   
    if ( id == 'Remote-Parking') {
        //document.getElementById('Popup-Emergency-Braking').style.display="block";
        console.log('IF');
    } else if ( id == 'Emergency-Braking' ){
        //document.getElementById('Popup-Remote-Parking').style.display="block";
        console.log('ELSE');
    } else {
        // in case id didn't find
        // do something;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `this` keyword as a parameter in the function call and manipulate it inside the function

```js
function modalFunction(e) {
if(e.getAttribute("id")=="Emergency-Braking")
console.log("Emergency-Braking");
if(e.getAttribute("id")=="Remote-Parking")
console.log("Remote-Parking");

}
```

```html
<div id="Remote-Parking" class="element parking"
onclick="modalFunction(this)">Remote-Parking</div>

<div id="Emergency-Braking" class="element collision-detection" onclick="modalFunction(this)">Emergency-Braking</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something similar to this:

```js
function modalFunction(val) {
 if(val == "park") {
  console.log("park");
 } else if(val == "brake") {
  console.log("brake");
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="Remote-Parking" class="element parking" onclick="modalFunction('park')">park</div>

<div id="Emergency-Braking" class="element collision-detection" onclick="modalFunction('brake')">brake</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the id as a argument in a function,

```
onclick="modalFunction('Remote-Parking')"
```

Now get the value by its parameter.

```
function modalFunction(val)
```

Then check the value in if/else condition

```
if (val === 'Emergency-Braking')
```

```js
//javascript
function modalFunction(val) {
    if (val === 'Emergency-Braking') {
        // document.getElementById('Popup-Emergency-Braking').style.display = "block";
        console.log("Emergency-Braking")
    }else if (val === 'Remote-Parking') {
        // document.getElementById('Popup-Remote-Parking').style.display = "block";
        console.log("Popup-Remote-Parking")
    }
}
```

```html
//html
<div id="Remote-Parking" class="element parking" onclick="modalFunction('Remote-Parking')">Remote-Parking</div>
<div id="Emergency-Braking" class="element collision-detection" onclick="modalFunction('Emergency-Braking')">Emergency-Braking</div>
```

I hope it would be your answer.